# How to force ECB to treat GUD buffers as comilation buffers?

Tags: emacs, emacs-ecb, gud

I've tried to do it in that way:

[image]

But it does not seem to be working. What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are telling emacs to treat "*gud*" as a regexp.

This means that "*guddddd" will match, but "*gud*" will not (it will contain a partial match, though).

Same for "*input/output*"

You can toggle the "Handled as a regexp" flag (see your screenshot)